# Can I set Views from code before inflating the whole layout in android?

Tags: android, layout, view, imageview

I can access, and set Views (view parameters) after I inflated the layout, declared at the xml file. 
However, in this case , the default layout (declared at xml file) loads first, and after a half second it disappears and the modified layout appears. It's very disturbing.

I tried to set the Views like this below, before inflating the layout,but it has no effect.

```
    imView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.talalat__imageView1);
    resID = getResources().getIdentifier("imagename", "drawable", getPackageName());
    bml.loadBitmap(resID,imView );

    talalat_View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talalat, null);

    talalat_View.setOnClickListener( osszecsap_ocl );
    setContentView(talalat_View);
```

Is there any way to set the Views parameters from code before inflating the layout?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, one remark: don't inflate using null as container reference.

Comment: Don't use `setContentView(...)` before inflating `talalat_View`. Inflate your view, find the widgets, add listeners etc, and then call `setContentView(talalat_View);`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem, but try:

```
    talalat_View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talalat, null);

    //Change this line
    imView = (ImageView) talalat_View.findViewById(R.id.talalat__imageView1);

    resID = getResources().getIdentifier("imagename", "drawable", getPackageName());
    bml.loadBitmap(resID,imView );
```

Comment: In this case , the default layout (declared at xml file) loads first, and after a half second it disappears and the modified layout appears. It's very disturbing, I would like to avoid this.